# HTML5 Tab including form and submit button

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, tabs

I have created a webpage where you can switch over to tabs London, Paris, Tokyo.
Every tab has a text field named comment 1, comment 2 and comment 3.
The Tab Tokyo has also a submit button, and once pressed on it, the input textfields comments 1,2,3 should be send to the server (broker4).
However, after opening of a webpage and pressing on tab 'London', the webpage immediately started to send to the server before I would type in the textfield comment 1.

Could you please have a look at the code below?

Best regards,

Cornelis

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<FORM ACTION="/scripts/broker4.exe" METHOD="FLAG" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" language="JavaScript" name="FrontPage_Form1" style="width: 844px" > 


<h2>Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>Enter text here.</p>
  <p><input type="text" name="comment1" value=""></p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Enter text here.</p> 
  <p><input type="text" name="comment2" value=""></p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Enter text here.</p>
  <p><input type="text" name="comment3" value=""></p>
  <p><input type="button" name="Send" value="Submit" onClick="location.href='http://nlgosas/scripts/broker4.exe?comment=&_SERVICE=emmerich&_PROGRAM=gvm.aaa.sas'"></p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
 
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="_SERVICE" SIZE="-1" VALUE="emmerich"><INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="_PROGRAM" SIZE="-1" VALUE="gvm.aaa.sas">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All your `<button class="tablinks"` are _submit_ buttons, and you did nothing in your JS to prevent the default action clicking on those has (submitting the form.) Add `type="button"` to make them mere click buttons.

Comment: Indeed, you are very right, this is very helpful. I didn't realize the default option.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all `<button>`s will submit whatever form they are inside of. To stop this, set their type to `"button"`:

```
<button class="tablinks" type="button" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable input, it is really helpful and in addition, other javascripts are working optimally.